# removing additional space above last line text in textfile c#

Tags: c#, string, append, stringbuilder

The following code is used by me to convert the entries in a datagrid view into a text file! (The process of creating a text file is successfull) After converting the datagrid view entries into a string I append a string from outside(This should appear on the last line of the textfile)

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // converting data grid value to single string
{
    StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            var val = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
            if (val == null)
                continue;//IF NULL GO TO NEXT CELL, MAYBE YOU WANT TO PUT EMPTY SPACE
            var s = val.ToString();
            file.Append(s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "));
        }

        file.AppendLine(); // NEXT ROW WILL COME INTO NEXT LINE
   }

   file.Append("Hello");
   using (StreamWriter sw = new
                   StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\sachinthad\Desktop\VS\Tfiles\file.txt"))
    {
        sw.Write(x);
    }   
}
```

But when I check text file the outside string("Hello" in this scenario) appears on the last line but there is an additional space above it! How can i remove this additional space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.Join`which concatenates a collection of strings with a separator in between. Together with refactoring it to use linq `.Select`:

```
var lines = dataGridView2.Rows.Select(row => string.Join(" ", 
                row.Cells.Select(cell => cell.Value).Where(val => val != null));
```

Then of course you can also use it on the entire collection of lines to concatenate them with a new line:

```
// Will eliminate problem of extra \n at the end
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

If you prefer having the loops instead of linq then what you can do in the inner loop is add the values to a `List<string>` initialized in the outer loop. After the inner loop ends to use `string.Join` on the values of that list. Psudocode:

```
for each row:
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    for each column in row:
        items.Add(value of column);
    file.Append(string.Join(" ", items));
```

Comment: thanx where do I have to place this code snippet? Inside the llops or after them?

Comment: @KasunKarunarathna - instead of the loops and `StringBuilder` :) Have a look at linq and `Select` :).

Comment: Actually I get an empty line above the last line isn't there a way to adjust my initial code to remve that empty line? :(

Comment: @KasunKarunarathna - yes :) the way is mentioned in the answer too. Use the `string.Join` on the entire `lines` collection as in the second code snippet.